# Changing a field name in JSON using jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I have a model class:

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Item {
    @JsonProperty("@context")
    String context;
    String type;
    String dateModified;
}
```

and I am setting the values for Item in service like:

```
Item exportItem = new Item();
        exportItem.setContext(exportConfig.getContext());
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        DateTimeFormatter customFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
        String formattedDate = customFormatter.format(localDateTime);
        exportItem.setDateModified(formattedDate);
        exportItem.setType(exportConfig.getType());
```

But when I see the JSON string:

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                    mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
                    Item bean = exportService.generate();
                    String result = mapper.writeValueAsString(bean);
```

the Json field for context, doesn't get renamed to @context.

How do I fix this issue?

Tried using @JsonProperty and expecting to see @context:value instead of context:value in my resulting json string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert Object to Json String but with @JsonProperty instead of field names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75142951/how-to-convert-object-to-json-string-but-with-jsonproperty-instead-of-field-nam)

Comment: No, I only use jackson and I am following the same. Somehow it doesn't work :(